# find the limit of the two variable function $f(x,y)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let $$f(x,y)=\cos\left(\frac{x^2+y^3}{x+y+1}\right)$$ Calculate the limit at origin.

My intuition is limits is exist and equal to $1$
along $y=mx$   $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)=1$ it is verified but how to proof using $\epsilon- \delta $ definition

$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,mx) \to 0} \cos\left(\frac{x^2+m^3x^3}{x+mx+1}\right)=1$$

**Edit**  Since $\cos x$ is a continuous function at the origin and the limit of $\left(\frac {x^2+y^3}{x+y+1}\right)$ exists at the origin then we can say the given limit exists but still I have no clue to proof using the definition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get the result for $y=mx?$

Comment: Since $x^2+y^3\to 0$ and $x+y+1\to 1,$ you only need to use standard proofs, but will require some knowledge of $\cos\theta$ to get an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.

Comment: Just substituting $y=mx$ doesn't show the limit. Why is that limit $1?$

Comment: That is just along one path to approach origin but we can't say limit exists or not.

Comment: Can you use continuity of functions? Because in this case, you have a limit of a composition of continuous functions at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Is it not a proper question to ask since I am a beginner  to study multivariable calculus

Comment: Your $f(x,mx)=\dots$ is also an abuse of notation. What you seem to mean is $\lim f(x,mx)=\lim \cos(\dots).$

Comment: No, still wrong, $f(x,y)$ is not equal to the limit. If $f(x,y)=\dots=1,$ then is all $f(x,y)=1?$ The equal sign means something.

Comment: I have edit my question, Am I on right track?

Comment: Your last big line is still wrong. It should be $\lim_{x\to0} f(x,mx)=\dots.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your edit, since $g(x) = cos(x)$ is continuous, all you have to do is prove that $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^3}{x+y+1} = 0$$
By definition of limit, we can assume that  $ -0.1 < x,y <0.1 \implies -0.2< x+y< 0.2 \implies 0.8 < 1+ x+y< 1.2$. Furthermore, $ |x| \geq |x|^2$ and $|y| \geq |y|^3$.
$|\frac{x^2+y^3}{x+y+1}-0|  = \frac{|x^2+y^3|}{|x+y+1|} \leq \frac{|x|+|y|}{0.8}$
For an arbitrary $\epsilon$, put $ |x|,|y|< 0.8 \times \epsilon/2$ which implies the  desired limit.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to prove this with $\epsilon-\delta$ is to show $$\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}\frac{x^2+y^3}{x+y+1}=0\tag1$$ and $$\lim_{\theta\to0}\cos\theta=1.\tag2$$

Once you've proved these, you can let $\epsilon>0.$ By $(2),$ there exists $\delta_1$ such that if $|\theta|<\delta_1$ then $|1-\cos(\theta)|<\epsilon.$

And by $(1),$ there exists a $\delta_2>0$ such that if $|(x,y)|<\delta_2$ then $$\left|\frac{x^2+y^3}{x+y+1}\right|<\delta_1.$$

Then you can show that $|1-f(x,y)|<\epsilon$ when $|(x,y)|<\delta_2.$

Showing $(2)$ amounts to showing cosine is continuous at $0,$ and depends on what you know about cosine, but, if you think you have to prove $(2),$ rather than just assert it, it really depends on how you define cosine.

$(1)$ is the real work. The numerator goes to $0$ and the denominator goes to $1,$ so you'd expect it true, but proving with $\epsilon-\delta$ will be fun, and is probably the heart of the problem.